# Retrieving the deselected node with jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

How to get the deselected node in jstree. To me it seems that the

```
domtree.bind("deselect_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
});
```

gives access only to the *selected* node, so does the select_node event. Why?

Answer (score 2):

there is a discussion group with the creator of jsTree here: http://groups.google.com/group/jstree the creator usually answers and bugfixes in the same day. I guess you'll have more luck there :)